# How to portably save two words of memory in paired structures?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, pointer-arithmetic

I have a data structure `struct foo` that always appears in pairs. Right now, each `struct foo` carries around a pointer to the other `struct foo` in its pair:

```
struct foo {
    struct foo *other_half;
    /* ... */
};
```

As my program requires many (> 1'000'000) `struct foo`, I'm eager to reduce the size of each one. Is there a way to get rid of the `other_half` pointer and find the other half of a pair of `struct foo` by other means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider an array `struct foo foos[2]` of two `struct foo` aligned to `2 * sizeof (struct foo)` or greater. Observe that `foos[0]` is aligned to `2 * sizeof (struct foo)` or greater whereas `foos[1]` is only aligned to `sizeof (struct foo)`. You can use that information to find out if a random `struct foo*` that points into such an aligned `struct foo[2]` points to the first or the second member.

To get sufficiently aligned memory, either write a custom allocator or use the C11 `aligned_alloc` function. Note that it is not really required to have the memory fully aligned, merely having the bit we test in `other_half` cleared is sufficient.

A naïve implementation of a function to find the other half of a pair of `struct foo` given a pointer to one half looks like this:

```
struct foo *other_half(struct foo *half) {
    if ((uintptr_t)half % (2 * sizeof *half) == 0)
        return half + 1;
    else
        return half - 1;
}
```

This function however is not very efficient if `sizeof (struct foo)` is not a power of two as it involves a slow modulo operation. To speed things up, consider the factorization of `sizeof (struct foo)` which is of the form 2<sup>*n*</sup> · *q*. It is easy to see that it is sufficient to check `((uintptr_t)half & (uintptr_t)1 << n) == 0` because `2 * sizeof (struct foo)` is a multiple of 2<sup>*n + 1*</sup> and therefore has the bits in positions 0 to *n* turned off.

Computing *n* at compile time is a bit tricky, but luckily we only need `1 << n`, which can be computed with a little bit magic as `-sizeof (struct foo) & sizeof (struct foo)`:

```
struct foo *other_half(struct foo *half) {
    if ((uintptr_t)half & -sizeof *half & sizeof *half)
        return half - 1;
    else
        return half + 1;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you avoid the alignment requirement by providing `other_half` with the parity of the first struct?  If `half & -sizeof(*half) & sizeof(*half)` is set, `(half + 1) & -sizeof(*half) & sizeof(*half)` is not and visa versa.  So they alternate, and if the block they are in is aligned, the first struct in the block will have that bit not set.  If the first struct in the block had the bit set instead, you could just flip the conditional.

Comment: @hacatu Yes, which is why I say: “Note that it is not really required to have the memory fully aligned, merely having the bit we test in other_half cleared is sufficient.”

Answer (score 0):

An alternate design with less trickery, but using single byte per `foo`; or bit if you pack the value together with some other field.

```
#include 
#include 

struct foo {
    char Index; // can be packed together with some other field
    /* ... */
};

typedef struct foo pair[2];

void init_pair(pair *p){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*p); i++){
        (*p)[i].Index = (char)(i);
    }
}

struct foo *pair_index(struct foo *piece, size_t index){
    return &piece[index - (size_t)piece->Index];
}

struct foo *pair_other(struct foo *piece){
    return pair_index(piece, piece->Index ^ 0x01);
}
```

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    pair p;
    init_pair(&p);

    struct foo *first = &(p[0]);
    struct foo *second = &(p[1]);

    printf("%p %p\n", pair_index(first, 0), pair_index(first, 1));
    printf("%p %p\n", pair_index(second, 0), pair_index(second, 1));
    printf("%p %p\n", pair_other(second), pair_other(first));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An extra bit is sadly not available as all structure members are pointers. I mean, I could repurpose the least significant bit of one of the pointers, but that makes debugging the code a real pain-in-the ass due to the pointers not pointing where they should. Doing this alignment trick seems simpler. Adding an extra flag to the structure is out of question, too. This entire thing is about saving memory, adding more data won't cut it.

Comment: Depending on the situation, aligned memory can waste/fragment memory, e.g. if you need to pad with 3-bytes to get things aligned.  If all of the fields are pointers and on x64; then you (probably) are wasting memory as well.

Comment: *(Note: I'm not saying that this is a "better" solution, just an alternate design that makes different trade-offs)*

Comment: I'm not wasting any memory. Read the trick again, one part of the pair is always going to have the higher alignment, so if you use a custom memory pool, you only have to throw away at most one entry in the large array you give structures away from. Note that in C, each structure contains implicit padding to a multiple of its minimum alignment by design (so arrays work correctly) making your point pretty much moot.